# javafx how to transfer variable values from one controller to another

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

i am new to javafx and i want to transfer `variable values` from one controller to another and i have no idea how to do this. so please help me.

for example:

i want to display username from `first login window` to `second dashboard window` so what should i do to save userid in one variable and send it to second window and display there in a `label`.

code test:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author wabcon
 */
public class AdmissionController implements Initializable {

int userid=0;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    userid=10001;

    }    

}
```

how could i send this `userid` to next window controller.
please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: i am new in javafx it to complicated can you explain in a simple way

Comment: You will need to understand the code in the answer to the existing question if you want to build the kind of application you are describing.

Comment: but i am unable to understand in that answer is `customer` is not set with any data how can i set data in `customer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am assuming you are doing this for a custom component.**

So, you create a class for your custom component and set that class as the controller:

```
public class CustomControl extends AnchorPane implements Initializable {
    String customId;

    public CustomControl() {
        //if you want to set a FXML
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/res/customControl.fxml"));
        //Defines this class as the controller
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        //this.getStylesheets().add("/res/style.css"); <- if you want to set a css
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }

    }
        public String getCustomId() {
            return customId;
        }
    public void setCustomId(String customId) {
        return this.customId = customId;
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
          //Initializes the controller
    }
}
```

On your MainController:

```
CustomControl c = new CustomControl();
c.setCustomId("StackOverflow");
```

Comment: i didn't understand, i want to send values

Comment: @user3204934, is it more clear now?

Comment: getting error for `String customId();`

Comment: @user3204934, sure you are. It was a typo, but you should be able to figure it out still.

Comment: code i used to set CustomId `AdmissionController c = new AdmissionController();
    c.setCustomId("StackOverflow"); 
        System.out.println(c.getCustomId());`  and to get  `AdmissionController c = new AdmissionController();
    c.getCustomId();
     System.out.println( c.getCustomId());` and i am getting output `StackOverflow`                                                      
`null` help me please..

Comment: i use `setCustomId` in different controller and `getCustomId` in different controller

Comment: please help me. how to  getCustomId();